# So what's the verdict about opening an attachment with a custom file extension from the Gmail Android app?

Tags: android-intent, gmail, attachment, intentfilter

There have been lots of questions about how to get files to open in our own Android apps using `<intent-filter>`. I just want to know, as of API 17, is intent resolution buggy and not to be relied upon or not?

Specifically:

- My files are binary data and they have a *custom* file extension (.mya)
- I'm opening the attachment in the *Gmail* app

I cannot get my app to show up in the application chooser using any scheme and pathPattern that matches `.mya`. The *only* way I get it to work is with

```
<data android:mimeType="*/*" android:host="*" />
```

...which of course allows all content types.

Comment: I'm finding Android a total disaster in this regard. Every app seems to do something different when 'opening' my identical binary file. No-one seems to properly understand how it works as there are dozens of different, contradictory answers on here.